# Stripe connect - save a card during payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to save a credit card during payment using stripe connect.

I am following the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment)

However, the docs are not for stripe connect. They are for regular stripe payments.

My code is the same as the docs except my paymentIntents is created on the connected account because I want the charge to be on the connected account.

```
                                stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                                    payment_method_types: ['card'],
                                    amount: Math.round(Number(req.body.stripeData.amount *100)),
                                    currency: userEvent.currency,
                                    description: userEvent.title,
                                    application_fee_amount: Math.round(Number((fees.applicationFee) *100)),
                                    customer: stripeCustomerID 
                                    },{
                                    stripe_account: sellerDetails.stripeAccountID,
                                    }
                                )
```

This is throwing me the error  `No such customer: 'cus_ITBFODvD6dB1vP'` which makes sense because the customer is set up on the platform account.

I want to save the customer and the payment method to my platform account and then charge on the connected account.

Is there a slick way I can do this similar to the docs or must I do a work around - code to save the customer and payment method on the platform account and then automatically charge it on the connected account

Answer (score 1):

You can create the Customer on the connected account instead of your platform by specifying the `stripe_account` in the Customer creation call as well.  Something like this:

```
stripe.customers.create({
    // Customer details here
},
{
    stripe_account: sellerDetails.stripeAccountID
});
```

You can use this technique to make almost any API call on behalf of a connected account instead of your platform account.  For more details check out [the documentation for authentication with Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication).

Note: It looks like you're using an older version of Stripe's Node library; the newer versions use `stripeAccount` instead of `stripe_account` in the last options object passed to the library methods.  Just something to watch out for if you upgrade to a newer version of the library!

Comment: Thanks for that. 

Won't this mean that the customers payment details are only saved in THAT connected account though?

I'd like to save their details on my platform account so that I can use their saved payment details on ANY connected account.

Comment: That's correct.  If you want the Customer and payment details saved to both your platform and your connected account you should look into [cloning your Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) and [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods).

Comment: So coding for strong customer authentication means that, to save a customers card for use on all connected accounts, I need to do the following steps:

1. on the backend create a customer and a setupIntent

2. on the frontend confirmCardSetup

3. on the backend again, clone the payment method to the connected account and create an off session payment intent.

4. display whether this was success or failure on the front end

This will work but given the customer is left waiting for all these calls to complete!